# Can I use fputs and fgets in file opened in binary

Tags: c, file, binary, append, fputs

The data in file is random and both alphabet and numbers.

```
/**** Program to APPEND one file after another file ****/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *fc;
    char data[200];

    fp = fopen("students.DAT", "ab");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fc = fopen("pr1.DAT", "rb");

    if (fc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file");
        exit(2);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    while (fgets(data, 199, fc) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(data, fp);
    }
    fputs("\n", fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Is the use of `fputs` and `fgets` in this program OK?
If not kindly tell the what to use and why `fgets`/`puts` is not ok?

Comment: Does your code work or not? Please [edit] and show the first 4-5 lines of `pr1.DAT`.

Comment: Does the file contain newlines?

Comment: Does the file contain 0 bytes?

Comment: If your file only contains alphabets and digits, why do you want to use binary? What does the concept of a "line" mean in a binary file?

Comment: Note that `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);` isn't necessary. A file opened for append writes at the end regardless of how you position the file pointer (that's what "append" means).

Comment: With `fputs("\n",fp);` why are you adding a newline that wasn't present in the original file? Anyway this means you are *expecting* a text file, so why did you open in binary?

Comment: `fgets(data, 199, fc)` can be `fgets(data, 200, fc)` or (better) `fgets(data, sizeof data, fc)`

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for suggesting sizeof data approach.

Comment: @Jabberwocky   what if just want to read the content of any file without knowing if it has text or numbers or symbols or newline in binary.what should i use then.Also can i read pdf through fputs/fgets?

Comment: @interjay what if just want to read the content of any file without knowing if it has text or numbers or symbols or newline in binary.what should i use then.Also can i read pdf through fputs/fgets?

Comment: @Gerhardh what if just want to read the content of any file without knowing if it has text or numbers or symbols or newline in binary.what should i use then.Also can i read pdf through fputs/fgets?

Comment: If you want to be able to read any data, then you cannot use any string or line oriented functions. No `fgets`/`fputs` etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh then what should be used for that? kindly explain.Thank you for replying to the comment

Comment: Sewe2000 already explained in an answer what functions you should use.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the first 4-5 lines of pr1.DAT.

Answer (score 1):

In binary mode you should use `fread` instead of `fgets` and `fwrite` instead of `fputs`. The difference is if you use `fwrite` function you should provide as arguments:

1. pointer to the array ( in your case data)
2. size of each element of the array in bytes
3. number of elements in the array
4. pointer to FILE

Comment: what if just want to read the content of file without knowing if it has text or numbers or symbols in binary.what should i use then.

Comment: @NitinBhartiya you should do exactly what is suggested in this answer.